# Not getting alerts but acknowledgement of the alerts on dashboard work

Tags: bosun

I have been trying to get Bosun to work with little success. Here are my problems:

1) I am able to see alerts appearing in my dashboard, but the alerts never come thru to the notification mode of my choice, be it e-mail, slack or json.

2) When I acknowledge the alerts on the dashboard, only one notification from the notification chain (first one) will be received. I.e. If I set up {email -> slack -> json}, only e-mail notification will be received, no slack and json.

Any help will be appreciated. Below is my dev.config

```
    -------------- dev.conf ---------------

    tsdbHost = qa1-sjc005-031:4242
    emailFrom = bosun-alert@noreply.com
    smtpHost = stmp.somedomain.com:25
    checkFrequency = 1m
    httpListen = :8070

    # Post to an endpoint
    notification json {
            post = http://somedomain.com/HealthCheck/bosunAlert
            body = {"text": {{.|json}}}
            contentType = application/json
            print = true
            next = json
            timeout = 5m

    }


    # Post to a Slack channel via Incoming Webhooks integration
    notification  slack {
            post = https://hooks.slack.com/services/T03DNM0UU/B04QH37J6/ypn0
                   Uy2JwLa676soomXwItjq
            body = payload={"channel":  "#testing", "username": "webhookbot"
                   , "text" : "This is a test!"}
            print = true
            next = json
            timeout = 5m

    }


    # Send out e-mail notification
    notification email {
            email = username@somedomain.com
            print = true
            next = slack
            timeout = 5m
    }

    template test {
            subject = {{.Last.Status}}: {{.Alert.Name}} on {{.Group.measurem
                      ent}} for {{.Group.pod}}
            body = `<p>Name: {{.Alert.Name}}
            <p>Tags:
            <table>
                    {{range $k, $v := .Group}}
                            <tr><td>{{$k}}</td><td>{{$v}}</td></tr>
                    {{end}}
            </table>`
    }



    alert test {
            template = test
            crit = avg(q("avg:mq1{measurement=*,pod=pod3}", "1h", ""))
            warn = avg(q("avg:mq1{measurement=*,pod=pod3}", "30m", ""))
            critNotification = email
            warnNotification = email
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Acknowledgements stop notification chains. So the purpose of them is really for the escalation of incidents; escalation stops when an incident has been acknowledged. As per the documentation on notifications:

> notification
>   A notification is a chained action to perform. The chaining continues until the chain ends or the alert is acknowledged.

It seems like you might want to send to multiple notifications at the same time. To do this list them out in warnNotification and/or critNotification as appropriate:

> critNotification: comma-separated list of notifications to trigger on critical.

Both the quotes are from the [configuration documentation](http://bosun.org/configuration) (documentation isn't that well organized currently, so I don't blame you for missing either of these)

Comment: Thank you, sir for your kind assistance. The multiple notifications worked as you suggested. But, I am still not getting new alerts via e-mail (and slack and json) as originally described even though they appeared on the dashboard. The only time I would get notifications via e-mail/slack/json is when I acknowledge the alerts on the dashboard.